# Pgen module not found during cython installation

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to install cython using
Py setup.py install

source. But the pgen executable is not found

Answer (score 0):

Solved using
`pip install Cython-0.29.21.tar.gz --install-option="--no-cython-compile"`